# How to add some text between date and hour with twig localizeddate extension

Tags: symfony, twig

This is my code

```
{{ commentaire.dateCommentaire|localizeddate('medium', 'medium') }}
```

and this is the output

```
12 MARS 2016 20:35:21
```

I'd like to add a text between date and hour to be like this

```
12 MARS 2016 à 20:35:21
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `format` option:

> format: Optional pattern to use when formatting or parsing. Possible
>   patterns are documented in the [ICU user guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

```
{{ commentaire.dateCommentaire|localizeddate('medium', 'medium', format='dd MMM yyyy à HH:mm:ss') }}
```